# HTTP response maximum content length for entire body to be in same chunk as headers

Tags: http, https, http-headers

## Context / TL;DR

I remember reading somewhere that under a certain body size (12ko?) there is some sort of optimization available in HTTP responses (which has a name like "HTTP fast start window" or something). What is its name and what is the max size?

## Details

To be more precise, it's not really an optimization in the sense that "it takes a different route", it's just that the request only needs a single chunk to get the entire response. For illustration purposes, here are 2 screenshots from **webpagetest.org**, one big HTML page where you can see several chunks (1st picture), and one very very small one with a tiny chunk at the end (2nd picture).

1. Cyan-orange-purple are the connection being established between the client and the server (you can ignore that part),
2. light blue / dark blue are the response, dark blue are chunks of HTML being downloaded from the server to the client.

In the case of the **bigger response** (1st picture), you can see that *the response is being sent in several chunks* (darker blue) while in the case of the **smaller response** (2nd picture), *it only takes a single chunk*.

[image: big HTML request, many chunks in the response]

[image: small HTML request, single tiny chunk in the response]

## Question

What is the name of this "optimization"? What is the maximum body size it can handle? Where can I read about it? Is it simply up to the implementation of the server or is it really somewhere in some specs?

---

PS: I'm not talking about streaming requests like `HTTP 206 Partial Content` here, nor the http/1 `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` standard, just a good old GET of a gzipped HTML page served by nginx or express or what have you.

Comment: Are you thinking of [TCP Fast Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Fast_Open)?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Maybe I got confused for the name, but I'm still convinced I read about the concept I'm explaining here and it had a name in the same vein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you receive any data from a server, your client connects to the server using, in most cases, a TCP connection. 
TCP has a maximum amount of data that you can send for packet (TCP segments) that is the MSS or maximum segment size. Another limiting factor is the maximum transmission unit, MTU, that depends on the minimum MTU of the routers in the path between your client and the server, and resulting in the maximum amount of bytes you can send for each packet.
The 12kB you are referring in your question i believe are relative to the:

- **MTU** and depends on the protocol in use and, for example, with ethernet the the MTU is 1518 bytes with the ethernet headers and 1500 bytes for the upper layer data.
- For the **MSS of TCP**, if the IPV4 and ethernet protocols are in use (so MTU data can accomodate up to 1500 bytes of data), is 1500 - 20(ip headers) - 20(tcp headers) giving a MSS of 1460 bytes(this value is not guaranteed, since client and server can negotiate the MSS value if they support a different MSS value during the TCP connection procedure).

The minimum of those values will prevale otherwise if you send a packet that exceeds the MTU the the first router in the path will drop the packet.

So if the page (or data) size exceeds the MSS, TCP will segment your data in multiple segments, thus requiring more time to be acknowledged and sent. But if the data you are sending is smaller than the MSS, only one segment will be used resulting in a smaller time to send the page or *"less chunks"*.

---

***This is just a brief explaination, of course the values used in the examples above are examples of general cases so they can be different for specific scenarios since are not fixed.*** 
Here you can find some more useful articles from wikipedia that might help with more insight:

- [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit)
- [TCP MSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_segment_size)
- [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)

Comment: You specifically mention ethernet several times. I don't know enough about the subject. Would being on 4G / 3G / Wifi... influence the size of the packets?

Comment: Yes, i referred to ethernet in my examples above because is the one i know the most among these. But, as you said, different medium, and in particular protocols, do matter in the packet transmission size, and the "drop packet" behaviour is similar among the protocols you mentioned, is just the actual supported maximum size that may change. The size related to TCP, that is an upper layer protocol, not related to the physical packet transmission, does not change and is limited by the underlying layers capabilities.